# SQL to join four tables

Tags: sql

Display a list of employees names,salaries,and the name of the city in which they work for IT developers who do not earn a comission who work in the operations department in Italy

I did this and it did not work

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary, l.city
FROM employees e
JOIN jobs j
    ON (j.job_id = e.job_id)
WHERE
    AND e.commission_pct = 0
    AND job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'
JOIN locations l
    ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)
        AND 
        (
            l.country LIKE '%Italy%'
            AND 
            department_name = 'Operations'
        );
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsbZ1.jpg and this is the link for my logical ERD

Comment: "it did not work" What did not work about it? Is there an error message? I can see several syntax errors in your SQL - there is a missing AND condition after the WHERE, and the JOIN clause needs to appear before the WHERE clause.

Comment: Also, scans of text are not useful in a post, since the text in them cannot be copied or searched. If the information on that page is necessary to answer the question, please [edit] and type in that information.

Comment: WHERE AND e.commission_pct = 0 AND 
job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'
join locations l        (it says these lines there is a syntax error also how can I put the scans picture into text

Comment: SELECT e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,l.city
FROM employees e join jobs j
ON(j.job_id = e.job_id)

join locations l 
ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)


WHERE  e.commission_pct = 0 AND 
job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'

AND (l.country LIKE '%Italy%'
AND department_name = 'Operations'), also where is your d table?

Comment: @Gautam thanks.I tried that but this error came #1054 - Unknown column 'department_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: I did not realized that you were missing departments in your query just added in the answer below, give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,l.city
FROM employees e join jobs j
ON(j.job_id = e.job_id)
join departments d ON (d.department_id=e.department_id)
join locations l 
ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)

WHERE e.commission_pct = 0 AND 
job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'

AND (l.country LIKE '%Italy%'
AND d.department_name = 'Operations')
```